# making a where clause optional in a sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT `performers`.`hash`,
        `performers`.`alias`,
        `performers`.`date_updated`,
        `performers`.`status`, 
        IF(`performers`.`status` = 'active', 'deleted','active') AS `statususe`,
        `images`.`image_hash_file` 
FROM `performers` 
LEFT JOIN `images` ON `images`.`asset_id` = `performers`.`id` 
WHERE (`images`.`asset_type` = 'performer') 
ORDER BY `alias` ASC LIMIT 12`
```

In it, there is a where clause

```
WHERE (`images`.`asset_type` = 'performer')
```

I'd like it to be optional, such that if there where clause doesn't fit it still shows the records from the performers table that do not have a join to the fulfilling images records.

Comment: WHERE `<clause>` OR `<something that is always true>` ?

Comment: i just want to make the where clause not binding

Comment: if it's not binding, why include it at all? You instead maybe want to have an `ORDER BY` or `GROUP BY` clause so that the results at the top of the list are the ones containing `performer`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "not binding", but maybe you're looking for something like: WHERE (`images`.`asset_type` = 'performer') OR (`images`.`asset_type` IS NULL)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add the WHERE clause in the LEFT JOIN so not matching rows are still in the result set.

```
SELECT `performers`.`hash`, `performers`.`alias`, 
  `performers`.`date_updated`, `performers`.`status`,
  IF(`performers`.`status` = 'active', 'deleted','active') AS `statususe`,
  `images`.`image_hash_file`
FROM `performers`
LEFT JOIN `images` ON `images`.`asset_id` = `performers`.`id` AND `images`.`asset_type` = 'performer'
ORDER BY `alias` ASC
LIMIT 12
```

The main difference between WHERE and ON clause is that the ON clause works during the JOIN when the WHERE clause works after everything have been joined making not matching rows to be removed from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
WHERE (`images`.`asset_type` = 'performer' OR `images`.`asset_type` IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is not the preferred solution.  It will return duplicate rows if `asset_type` takes on a `NULL` value as well as `performer`.

Comment: This question wasn't clear. If that's the case you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the `where` condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT p.`hash`, p.`alias`, p.`date_updated`, p.`status`, 
       IF(p.`status` = 'active',  'deleted', 'active') AS statususe,
       i.`image_hash_file` 
FROM `performers`  p LEFT JOIN
     `images`i
     ON i.`asset_id` = p.`id` and
        i.`asset_type` = 'performer' 
ORDER BY `alias` ASC
LIMIT 12
```

I also modified the query to use table aliases.  They make queries much easier to write and to read.